# using nsurlconnection calculate remaining time for download

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

I am downloading a 25+ mb file from the server. Is there a way to predict the remaining time to download ? if yes how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ASIHTTPRequest instead of NSURLConnection, there are delegate methods to report total size and progress. If you're looking to hook up a progress bar, there's a very simple method to do exactly that.

Comment: greate ! Any other way with nsurlconnection ?

Comment: @thndrkiss - Wouldn't know. Once I discovered the joy that is ASIHTTPRequest, I quit using NSURLConnection and never looked back. I haven't used NSURLConnection in literally six months, and I've done a TON of HTTP client work.

Comment: @DanRay Please help me about the same issue..
how to know the remaining time and total time of current download file with help of ASIHttp request. ?

Comment: Since I posted this answer, ASIHTTPRequest is now deprecated and abandoned, and its author recommends using something else. AFNetworking seems to be a popular choice. That said, The docs on tracking progress in ASI are here: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#tracking_download_progress_for_a_single_request